# How can I automatically open the Hyper-V VM console on server boot on Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I am looking for advice on getting my Hyper-V VM to open on logon to the server. It currently runs in the background as a service however we required to have it automatically open so the user can view it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create shortcut to one of these utilities to users startup folder or create task after user logon.

Administration MMC module:
`C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\virtmgmt.msc`

Run Virtual PC: `C:\Program Files\Hyper-V\vmconnect.exe YOURHOST "NameOFVPC"`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have a virtual machine called Wonderware, this is located on the same server as the user will be logging on. I have tried to add the shortcut to run the virtual machine but it cannot find the file.

Comment: Have you tried it with Admin rights?

Comment: All sorted, I am not sure what was wrong. The only account is an admin account. All working now. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working today - but on an R2 server it was located in C:\Windows\System32 - and yes you must "RUNAS ADMIN" for it to work.  The rest of these instructions worked perfectly.